# Getting empty list after running scaping code in python to get reviews of users from play store of my app

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Send a GET request to the web page
response = requests.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app&reviewSortOrder=4&reviewType=0')

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find all the review divs
review_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='single-review')

# Extract the review data from each review div
reviews = []
for review_div in review_divs:
    # Extract the review text
    review_text = review_div.find('span', class_='review-body').text
    # Extract the reviewer's name
    reviewer_name = review_div.find('span', class_='author-name').text
    # Extract the review rating
    review_rating = review_div.find('div', class_='tiny-star').get('aria-label').split(' ')[1]
    
    # Store the review data in a dictionary
    review = {
        'review_text': review_text,
        'reviewer_name': reviewer_name,
        'review_rating': review_rating
    }
    
    # Add the review dictionary to the list of reviews
    reviews.append(review)

print(reviews)
```

I wrote this code to scrap reviews of my app from Playstore in tabular format. However, I am only getting empty block after running this code, I am not able to identify where I am making error in this code to get.Results I am expecting are list of all of the reviews of my app users.

Comment: Print your status, see what it returns
`print(response.status_code)`

Answer (score 0):

> *Print your status, see what it returns `print(response.status_code)`* –
> Samuel

You should always check `response` first. I usually add a line after a `request.get` call with something like

```py
print(response.status_code, response.reason, 'from', response.url)
```

so that I can see if the response is [ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) and also so that I'll know if the request was redirected to another page. (You can also proceed conditionally with `if response.status_code == 200`  or [`if response.ok`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-ok-python-requests/), or interrupt the program by raising an error in case of a bad response with [`response.raise_for_status()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-raise_for_status-python-requests/))

In this case, the link itself also appears to be problematic
[image: 404]